# Work with AccessibilityIdentifier from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, identifier

I want to change string or textColor for label inside the UITableViewCell when I click button.

Here the code while I use "let" which is not working, example:

```
var  reminderAddNewTableview = UITableView()

// Inside the tableCell:
let textButtonClicked = UILabel()
textButtonClicked.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 100)
textButtonClicked.text = "Test"
textButtonClicked.accessibilityIdentifier == "Reminder Add Note"
view.addSubview(textButtonClicked)

// When I click the button:
for testviewtag in reminderAddNewTableview.subviews {
   if testviewtag.accessibilityIdentifier == "Reminder Add Note" {
      testviewtag.text = "Change text, working"
      testviewtag.textColor = .green
   }
}
// Nothing happen.
```

Here the code while I use "var" which fine just perfectly, example:

```
var reminderAddNewTableview = UITableView()
var textButtonClicked = UILabel()

// Inside the tableCell:
textButtonClicked.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 100)
textButtonClicked.text = "Test"
textButtonClicked.accessibilityIdentifier == "Reminder Add Note"
view.addSubview(textButtonClicked)

// When I click the button:
if textButtonClicked.accessibilityIdentifier == "Reminder Add Note" {
   testviewtag.text = "Change text, working"
   testviewtag.textColor = .green
}
// It working very good.
```

I would like practice how to get accessibilityIdentifier from UITableViewCell, is there way possible able to get accessibilityIdentifier from UITableViewCell inside the UITableView so I don't have to add the "var"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue myself. Here code:

```
for gettableviewsubview in reminderAddNewTableview.subviews {
   for getaccideninfo in gettableviewsubview {
      print(getaccideninfo.accessibilityIdentifier)
   }
}
```

Finally it show and I was able to change string and text color.